# Tomcat7 doesn't start and show no error message

Tags: java, tomcat7, server

I'm facing a problem trying to start/restart tomcat7.

When I do start/restart, the service seems to be starting/restarting ok:

```
* Stopping Tomcat servlet engine tomcat7                                 [ OK ] 
* Starting Tomcat servlet engine tomcat7                                 [ OK ]
```

However, checking the log, I found this:

```
Oct 22, 2014 11:48:14 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Oct 22, 2014 11:48:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 721 ms
Oct 22, 2014 11:48:14 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Oct 22, 2014 11:48:14 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.52 (Ubuntu)
Oct 22, 2014 11:48:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/manager.xml
```

and nothing else happens. The cpu seems to be OK and the memory too. It just got stuck in that point.

This issue appears suddenly because no change was made, no updates on tomcat or changes in the artifact that I'm trying to deploy.

What could be the problem?

Comment: What symptoms are you seeing that make you believe there is an issue?

Comment: How long have you seen it get hung up at that point? Have you tried removing you artifact, then redeploying it?